# Karate: parametric json path expressions

Tags: karate

I have a variable with some value:

```
* def some_string = "a manufacturer"
```

I want to use that value inside a json path expression:

```
Given path 'devices/'
When method get
Then status 200
And def device_search = $.device[?(@.manufacturer == some_string)]
```

I'm having an error:

pairing.feature:14 - Failed to parse filter: [?(@.manufacturer == some_string)], error on position: 21, char: s

How can I use variables inside json path?

Thanks