# Karate JSON filter paths not able to be parametrize

Tags: karate

I am trying to dynamically substitute the value 'US' in the below expression.
where in configs is an array not a json object.

```
* def selectedConfig= $configs[?(@.configId=='US')]
```

#this above one works

But I am not successful making it a dynamic expression. I tried the below variant and fe, please help

```
* def activeConfigId = 'US'
* def selectedConfig= karate.jsonPath("$configs[?(@.configId=='" + activeConfigId + "')]")
```

I see there is someone else also asked similar question but no answer how to make this expression dynamic.
[Karate: parametric json path expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63239371/karate-parametric-json-path-expressions)

Comment: next time. PLEASE provide an example that people can cut-and-paste and try locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the docs and examples a little more carefully. Here is an example that works:

```
* def configId = 'US'
* def response = [{configId: 'AA', data: 'first'}, {configId: 'US', data: 'second'}]
* def selectedConfig = karate.jsonPath(response, "$[?(@.configId=='" + configId + "')]")
* match selectedConfig[0] == { configId: 'US', data: 'second' }
```

If using `karate.jsonPath()` is too hard, please look at `karate.filter()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62897131/143475

And since you seem to be trying to do some smart config switching, refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49693808/143475